# SIGABRT error after IB fix attempted

Tags: xcode, runtime-error

I deleted PopoverContentViewController m, h, and xib files I no longer needed. When I ran, the program stopped with the error message on the console

“Unknown class PopoverContentViewController in Interface Builder file”

I looked up the problem in these pages and tried one fix. I added the files back again (with File New). The program ran past the problem, loaded the default.png, then stopped at int retVal in main.m with

Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT."

No error message on the console.

Any idea what I should try now?

(Do I ever wish I hadn't deleted those viewcontrollers I was no longer using!)

Any ideas of what I can do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the SIGABRT problem:

On my main VC xib, I had moved some labels off the view, or buried them behind others, that I no longer needed. I couldn't see them. When I deleted (commented out) the IBOutlet for the label in the .h, the program bombed with that rather uninformative message.

Fix: bring up the xib. Click the little rewind button at the bottom left, or go Editor/Show Document Outline. Expand View from the pane that appears. Find the name of the label or outlet you don't want. Press delete. Now you can safely remove it from the .h file.

Huge relief, and a little self-congratulations for creating a snapshot before I had begun the tidying of the code, and removing code by commenting out and running before deleting it permanently.